# Div pop out in new window and pop in with content to on its place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I hope every one familiar with gmail chat where you can pop out your chat window in to new window with its content and if you press the pop-in that new window will be placed in that previous position

I did some work around for that and the following is my problem

I am able to open the content in new window with out its content for example if I have typed in the text box in child.html which is inside the iframe is not showing when on the popout.

**Opener**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Popup checking</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var winObj;
function openwindow()
{
    winObj=window.open("","_blank","height=200,width=400,status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no");
    var s=document.getElementById('page').innerHTML;
    console.log(s);

winObj.document.write(s);


}
function changeValue()
{
    console.log(winObj.document.getElementById('changer').value);
    winObj.document.getElementById('changer').value='changer';
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="page">
        <iframe src="child.html" width="100" height="100"></iframe>
   </div>
   <div id="page1">
    <input type="text" id="text1"/>
    <input type="button" value="popup" onclick="openwindow()"/>
    <input type="button" value="changevalue" onclick="changeValue()"/>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Child**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openerChange()
    {
            window.opener.document.getElementById('text1').value="Value changed.."
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" value="" id="changer" />
    <input type="button" value="changed" onclick="openerChange()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see a single question mark.

Answer (score -1):

You need a semicolon.

```
function openerChange()
{
        window.opener.document.getElementById('text1').value="Value changed..";
}
```

Comment: I am not expecting this one.... its working with out that semi colon also, but what I need is while the child window in parent window and user typing the content in the child window then pressing the popup, now child window will pop up in new window where the typed content is not appear in that newly opened window.